# grep skip n lines of file and only search after

Tags: grep

I have a huge log file and want to grep the first occurrence of a pattern, and then find another pattern **right after** this occurence.

For example:

```
123
XXY
214
ABC
182
558
ABC
856
ABC
```

In my example, I would like to find `182` and then find the **next** occurrence of `ABC`

The first occurrence is simple:

```
grep -n -m1 "182" /var/log/file
```

This outputs:

```
5:182
```

How do I find the next occurrence of ABC?

My idea was to tell `grep` to skip the first `n` lines (in the above example `n=5`), based on the line number of 182. But how do I do that?

Comment: Is it a requirement that `grep` is used? I don't think this can be done with `grep` but it would be easy with `awk` or `sed` (alone or in combination with `grep`).

Comment: @HaukeLaging `grep` is not required. I am not so familiar yet with `sed` or `awk`. If you have a good solution, let me hear it! :)  @don_crissti only the first line should be printed. I don't care about the other occurrences.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

With `sed` you can use a range and `q`uit input at a single completion:

```
sed '/^182$/p;//,/^ABC$/!d;/^ABC$/!d;q'
```

Similarly w/ GNU `grep` you can split the input between two `grep`s:

```
{ grep -nxF -m1 182; grep -nxF -m1 ABC; } <<\IN
123
XXY
214
ABC
182
558
ABC
856
ABC
IN
```

... which prints...

```
5:182
2:ABC
```

... to signify that the first `grep` found a `-F`ixed-string literal, `-x`entire-line ***182*** match 5 lines from the start of its read, and the second found a similarly typed ***ABC*** match 2 lines from the start of its read - or 2 lines *after* the first `grep` *quit* reading at line 5.

From `man grep`:

```
-m NUM, --max-count=NUM
          Stop  reading  a  file  after  NUM  matching
          lines.   If the input is standard input from
          a regular file, and NUM matching  lines  are
          output, grep ensures that the standard input
          is  positioned  to  just  after   the   last
          matching  line before exiting, regardless of
          the  presence  of  trailing  context  lines.
          This  enables  a calling process to resume a
          search.
```

I used a here-document for the sake of reproducible demonstration, but you should probably do:

```
{ grep ...; grep ...; } </path/to/log.file
```

It will also work with other shell compound-command constructs like:

```
for p in 182 ABC; do grep -nxFm1 "$p"; done </path/to/log.file
```

Comment: +1 Saw that in the man page. That's what I tried, only with a pipe between the `grep`'s instead of a `;`... no-go

Comment: @Xen2050 - the pipe won't work, usually - an lseekable file is usually what you want when sharing input.

Comment: Impressive answer but I don't support your statement about pipelines. The here document which the two `grep`s share is effectively a pipeline for them. Something else: I tried without printing the marker line but `sed '//,/^ABC$/!d;/^ABC$/!d;q'` throws a strange error. What does `//` do?

Comment: @HaukeLaging - the here-document *(in most shells)* is not a pipe - it is a real tmp file created by the shell that the shell deletes before doing any writes - while maintaining the descriptor. It is still lseekable. Pipes, generally, are not lseekable. I'll look at the `sed` thing - just wrote it out real fast.

Comment: @HaukeLaging - Oh, so the `sed` thing works - you just left out the reference. In `sed` you can refer to the last `/address/` again with an empty `//` address. So `/^182$/command;//,/next_address/` just does `/^182$/command;/^182$/,/next_address/`. Your error was probably *no previous regular expression* if you were using a GNU `sed`. The pipe lseek thing, by the way, can be manipulated via indirection through the `/dev/fd/[num]` links on linux systems - but if you're not very careful to handle buffers well *(like with `dd`)* that's usually a losing battle.

Answer (score 2):

Use `grep` with Perl-compatible regular expressions (`pcregrep`):

```
pcregrep -Mo '182(.|\n)*?\KABC'
```

Option `-M` allow  pattern  to  match  more than one line, and `\K` does not include matched pattern (up to this point) into the output. You can remove `\K` if you want to have the whole region as a result.

Answer (score 2):

```
> awk '/^182$/ { startline=1; }; startline == 0 { next; }; /^ABC$/ { print "line " NR ": " $0; exit; }' file
line 7: ABC
```

Comment: That gives the first ABC *anywhere*; this question wants the first ABC *after* the first 182. Most direct is a flag like `awk '/^182$/{z=1;next} z&&/^ABC$/{print NR":"$0;exit}' file` -- or you can write at least one explicit `getline()` loop which is usually clumsier, or be clever(?) using a range almost like @JRFerguson's perl: `awk '!x&&/^182$/,/^ABC$/ {x=NR":"$0} END{print x}`

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 Indeed. Right idea but terribly coded (mixed up two ideas during writing). Embarraringly I even tried but didn't wonder at the output.

Answer (score 1):

A Perl variation you could use is:

```
perl -nle 'm/182/../ABC/ and print' file
```

...which prints lines in the matching range.

If you file contained more than one matching range, you can limit the output to only the first range by changing the `/` delimiter to `?`

```
perl -nle 'm?182?..?ABC? and print'
```

Answer (score 1):

Another variant is this:

```
grep -n -A99999 "182" /var/log/file|grep -n -m1 "ABC"
```

The flag -An greps n lines after the match and 99999 is just to be sure we don't miss anything. Bigger files should have more lines (check with "wc -l").

Answer (score 0):

Sticking with just `grep` and adding `tail` & `cut`, you could...

grep for the line number of the first match of `182`:

```
grep -m 1 -n 182 /var/log/file |cut -f1 -d:
```

Use that to grep for all the `ABC`'s only after the first matching line above, using `tail`'s `-n +K` to output after the K'th line. All together:

```
tail -n +$(grep -m 1 -n 182 /var/log/file |cut -f1 -d:) /var/log/file | grep ABC
```

Or add `-m 1` again to find only the first matching `ABC`

```
tail -n +$(grep -m 1 -n 182 /var/log/file|cut -f1 -d:) /var/log/file|grep -m 1 ABC
```

References:
`man` pages
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6958841/use-grep-to-report-back-only-line-numbers

Answer (score 0):

The range operator `,` can be put to use here:

```
< yourfile \
sed -e '
   /182/,/ABC/!d
   //!d;=;/ABC/q
' | sed -e 'N;s/\n/:/'
```

The range operator `..` in tandem with the match-only-once operator `m??` can be put to use here in `Perl`

```
perl -lne 'm?182? .. m?ABC? and print "$.:$_" if /182/ || /ABC/' yourfile
```